# SortTV perl script error

Tags: linux, perl, sorting

I'm trying to use a perl script named SortTV (http://sourceforge.net/projects/sorttv/)
Every dependencies is installed but I got an error & can't understood it...

It's not a specific problem of the script I think (that's why I'm posting here)

```
INFO: trying to move Criminal Minds season 09 episode 5
DBM::Deep: '1729971': Don't know what to do with type 't   
/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/TVDB/API.pm line 532
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Please include the command you ran, what parameters did you use? What is the name of the file being moved? Does it contain `'t`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a similar problem, just try to reboot.
It solved my problem !